# JSON Jquery How to put array elements into div?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to add elements from a JSON array into a div using JQuery. I'm very new to JSON so I'm not sure how exactly to do it.

The part of the JSON code I'm working on is:

```
"data":{
    "temp":["10","20","30","40","50","60","70","80","90","100"]....
```

My code looks like:

```
var url = "..."

 $.getJSON(url, function(data) {


 var i;
 for (i=0; i<5; i++)
 {
     $("#div").append(data.temp[i]); 
 }

});

}
```

It works if I append text but I can't get it to do work with the array. I've searched around online to try and figure it out but nothing seems to work and I don't know enough about JSON to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to parse json to get values http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: are you encountering any errors?

Comment: I suppose it should be `data.data.temp[i]` as `data`(1st) is the variable containing json object received which then contains `data`(2nd) as aa key to get value `temp`

Comment: I get no errors...just nothing shows up. I also tried data.data.temp[i] and parsing the data but those don't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I ll suggest you to use Ajax call to get data from url.

Here in above scenario inside your function it should look like

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
var array = data.temp;
var htmlData = "";
for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
     htmlData += "<p>"+array[i] + "</p>";
}
```

$("#div").html(htmlData);

Comment: It still doesn't do anything :/

Comment: Are you sure your function is getting called?  Check in browser console window about the error. Can you post your errors here?

Comment: The error it gives me in the console log is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o" and it doesn't give me a line number but has  "VM1093:1" if that means anything

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var url = "...";
var $targetBlock = $('#div'); // we'll paste data into #div

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var temp = ($.parseJSON(data)).temp;
    $.each(temp, function(index, el) {
        $('<p>' + el + '</p>').appendTo($targetBlock);
    });
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't do anything unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Apparently all I had to was parse and do data.data.temp like this:

```
var url = "..."

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));

var i;
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    $("#div").append(data.data.temp[i]); 
}

});

}
```